# Extracting any kind of information from the app

Tags: ingress

Is there a way to export or extract any kind of data from the ingress app?

For example can we get a list of our keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way at the moment to obtain those informations without breaking the TOS.

We're still waiting for the release of public APIs, that are probably going to be released [next year](http://goo.gl/YQEx99). In the meantime you'll have to rely on handcrafted spreadsheets or your own memory.